# Language options that cause public function not to work

Tags: php, yii2

I wrote the code below to check the completeness of a user's profile.

```
public function checkProfile() {
    if(Yii::$app->user->identity->profile_completed == 0){
        if(Yii::$app->request->referrer){
            $url = parse_url(Yii::$app->request->referrer);            
            return $this->redirect($url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'].'?profile_not_complete');
        }else{
            return $this->redirect(\yii\helpers\Url::home(true).'?profile_not_complete');
        }            
    }
}
```

If user's profile is incomplete then he/she cannot go to the certain page. The problem is my website has two language options (Chinese, English) and if current language is Chinese language then this piece of code works and with alert it restricts the user to go to that certain page. But if you switch the language into English then the code doesn't work and the user can easily go to the banned page without profile completion. If you know what can cause this problem please share with me your opinion.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what means `doesn't work`?

Comment: the purpose of the code is to check the profile completion. It must ban a user to go to the certain page if the user's profile information is incomplete. The problem is when the current language is Chinese then everything is okay (it bans the user), if you switch the language into English then for some reason user can go that certain page without completing the profile information, which is wrong

Comment: Right now, youre setting just url param in redirect, instead of this you should prepare individual page to handle profile completion. Your problem can't be solved with only this piece of code, because we don't see how's param `profile_not_complete` is handled.